# SQL Error 1064, Syntax error received

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I got an error for `eaysocial` extension as:

> 1064 YOU HAVE AN ERROR İN YOUR SQL SYNTAX; CHECK THE MANUAL THAT
>   CORRESPONDS TO YOUR MYSQL SERVER VERSİON FOR THE RİGHT SYNTAX TO USE
>   NEAR 'OR `A`.`İD` NOT IN (SELECT `CATEGORY_İD` FROM
>   `BLUE_SOCİAL_CLUSTERS_CATEGORİES_A' AT LİNE 1 SQL=SELECT DISTINCT`
>   A`.* FROM`BLUE_SOCİAL_CLUSTERS_CATEGORİES`AS`A`LEFT JOIN`
>   BLUE_SOCİAL_CLUSTERS_CATEGORİES_ACCESS`AS`B`ON`A`.`İD`=`
>   B`.`CATEGORY_İD`WHERE`A`.`TYPE`= 'EVENT' AND`A`.`STATE`= '1' AND
>   (`B`.`PROFİLE_İD`= OR`A`.`İD`NOT IN (SELECT`CATEGORY_İD`FROM`
>   BLUE_SOCİAL_CLUSTERS_CATEGORİES_ACCESS`)) ORDER BY`A`.`ORDERİNG`

I have searched in codes and forums. But I didn't find a solution for me. Please help for fixing this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I read correctly, your Query says this :

```
WHERE ... AND ... AND (B.PROFILE_ID = OR A.ID NOT IN (query...))
```

So B.PROFILE_ID = OR A.ID , you miss a value before the "OR".